# Load balancers - performance

Tags: performance, load, load-balancing

DNS A records of big sites like Google and Bing suggest that the there are few load balancers for each of them (1  for Bing and 14 for google). How come these few loadbalancers handle so much traffic? I think the load is too much even though they have to just proxy pass and proxy reverse pass to one of the actual servers behind. Can someone help me understand this?